# Как сделать в одном header два фоновых цвета

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

https://prnt.sc/qhj0vb
Как сделать в одном `header` два фоновых цвета. То-есть в первом блоке золотой цвет мы его ставим с помощью класс `.header` , а во втором блоке черный фоновый цвет и когда, я его ставлю в класс `.header-menu` он принимает значение класса `.container` и его ширина становится 1100px(container).
 Как сделать что бы второй фон был во всю ширину?

```html
 <header class="header">
  <div class="header-container">
   <div class="top-header">      //первый блок с золотым цветом
    <div class="languages">РУС</div>
    <div class="languages">ENG</div>
    <div class="languages">FR</div>

    <div class="top-header__number">8 (800) 123-45-67</div>
     <div class="top-header__email">sales@log.ru</div>
   </div>
   <div class="header-menu"> Второй блок с черным цветом
    
   </div>
  </div>
 </header>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не могу сказать на сколько это правильно но разделить header на два блока ... примерно та как в сниппете

Здесь актуальная версия с которой можно работать и можно исправлять: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/ZEYXBVr

Вторая версия на градиентах: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/ZEYXLzR?editors=1100

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 980px;
  margin: auto;
}

menu {
  background-color: #c8a35f;
}

menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: 0;
}

menu p {
  text-align: center;
}

menu p a {
  color: #fff;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
}

ul li {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

ul li a {
  color: #fff;
}

.preview {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background: #2f343a;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.company {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 300px;
  border-right: 1px solid;
}

.logo-text p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #fff;
}

.logo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 6px solid #fff;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.logo-text p:first-child {
  font-size: 34px;
}

.logo-text p:last-child {
  font-size: 20px;
}

@media (max-width: 680px) {
  ul li a {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  .logo {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
  }
  .logo-text p:first-child {
    font-size: 28px;
  }
  .logo-text p:last-child {
    font-size: 17px;
  }
  menu p a {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  .logo {
    margin-left: 80px;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <menu>
    <p>
      <a href="#">rus</a>
      <a href="#">eng</a>
      <a href="#">fr</a>
    </p>
    <p><a href="#">8(700)1234567</a> </p>
    <p><a href="#">mail@mailto.ru</a> </p>
  </menu>
  <div class="preview">
    <div class="preview-item">
      <div class="company">
        <div class="logo"></div>
        <div class="logo-text">
          <p>company</p>
          <p>lorem ipsum sit</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="preview-item">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Услуги</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">О компании</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Вакансии</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
header {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
.top-header {
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
    <div class="header-container">
        <div class="top-header">      //первый блок с золотым цветом
            <div class="languages">РУС</div>
            <div class="languages">ENG</div>
            <div class="languages">FR</div>

            <div class="top-header__number">8 (800) 123-45-67</div>
          <div class="top-header__email">sales@log.ru</div>
        </div>
        <div class="header-menu"> Второй блок с черным цветом

        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Получается такое prnt.sc/qhk4kd , а мне нужно что бы фон растянулся

Comment: Дайте свой html со стилями, по скринам ничего не понятно

Answer (score 0):

Можно задать для "header-container" размер  1100px, а для top-header и header-menu те цвета, которые надо.

```css
    .header-container {
      max-width: 1100px;
    }
    
    .top-header {
      background: green;
    }
    
    .header-menu {
      background: black;
    }
```

```html
     <header class="header">
      <div class="top-header">
        <div class="header-container">
          //первый блок с золотым цветом
          <div class="languages">РУС</div>
          <div class="languages">ENG</div>
          <div class="languages">FR</div>

          <div class="top-header__number">8 (800) 123-45-67</div>
          <div class="top-header__email">sales@log.ru</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="header-menu">
        <div class="header-container">
          Второй блок с черным цветом
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: Получается такое https://prnt.sc/qhk4kd , а мне нужно что бы фон растянулся

Comment: @Primo Вы, скорее-всего, неправильно прописали стили. Посмотри на мой код - я добавил стили

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, перенести контейнер во внутрь каждого из блоков header и задавать фон соответственно для top-header и header-menu

```html
 <header class="header">      
   <div class="top-header">      //первый блок с золотым цветом
                           <div class="header-container">
    <div class="languages">РУС</div>
    <div class="languages">ENG</div>
    <div class="languages">FR</div>

    <div class="top-header__number">8 (800) 123-45-67</div>
       <div class="top-header__email">sales@log.ru</div>
     </div>
                      </div>
   <div class="header-menu"> Второй блок с черным цветом
                          <div class="header-container">

     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </header>
```